# difference between (void*) and &

Tags: c++

Hi I've been exercising with placement new and using it to create objects.
Consider the following:

```
class PNewTesting
{
private:
    string words;

public:
    PNewTesting(const string & w = "Placement new testing");
};

PNewTesting::PNewTesting(const string & w)
{
    words = w;
    cout << words << " constructed" << endl;
}


int main()
{
    char * buffer = new char[BUF];

    PNewTesting *p1,*p2;

    p1 = new (buffer)PNewTesting;

    p2 = new PNewTesting("Placing object in heap");

    cout << "Memory addresses: " << endl;
    cout << "buffer: " << (void *)buffer << endl;
    cout << "object placed in buffer: " << p1 << endl;
    cout << "object in heap: " << p2 << endl;
}
```

The part is is confusing me, is that when I write `cout << "buffer: " << &buffer << endl;`,
this would give me a different address to when writing `cout << "buffer: " << (void *)buffer << endl;`

The question is what is the difference between `&buffer` and `(void*)buffer`, and why does each one of them give me a different address.

Comment: This is completely unrelated to placement new, btw.

Comment: Ah sorry, just a C++ beginner so didn't realize that.

Comment: That's perfectly fine. But now you know :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question can be **[essentially reduced to](http://ideone.com/JqswSi)**:

```
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int *ptr = &i;

    std::cout<<(void*)ptr<<"\n";
    std::cout<<(void*)&i<<"\n";
    std::cout<< &ptr<<"\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
0xbfa080b8
0xbfa080b8
0xbfa080bc
```

`ptr` gives you the address of object the pointer is pointing to i.e same as `&i`.
`&ptr` gives the address of the location where the pointer itself is stored.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The thing that I'm still not quite understanding is what does (void*)&i do? All I know is that it casts i to a void type, but not too sure about the purpose of that.

Comment: @AliAlamiri: Casting the address of a integer pointer does not make much sense. Casting the address of pointer to char(`char *`) is required when you need to output the address with `std::cout`, because unless you do so `operator <<` interprets that as an char string and tries to print the character sequence instead of an address. Note that this ambiguity arises because `operator <<` provides an [overload for char pointers](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/)

Answer (score 1):

The expression `&buffer` will give you the address of `buffer`, which is somewhere on your stack.

The expresson `(void *)buffer` will give you the address contained in buffer, as a void pointer (in this case, that means that the `cout` will print the value as a hexnumber representing the pointer, rather than trying to, for example, print the value as a string, which would be what the code would normally do with a `char *`.

Answer (score 1):

One of those displays the address of a variable, the other displays the value of the variable. Consider these:

```
int i = 7;
std::cout << &i << "\n";
std::cout << i << "\n";
```

The former displays the address of the variable called `i` (likely a large even number). The other displays its value (7).

Similarly:

```
char *buffer;
std::cout << &buffer << "\n";
std::cout << (void*)buffer << "\n";
```

The former displays the address of `buffer`. The latter displays its cast value.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is simple. `buffer` is a pointer-to-char, so `(void*)buffer` is the location in memory of the allocated character array (as a `void` pointer). `&buffer`, on the other hand, is the location in memory of `buffer` *itself*.

A diagram may help; **this is symbolic of what's happening and doesn't represent what the actual memory layout will look like!**

```
Memory
AB AB AB AB 00 00 00 08  <-- buffer = 00 00 00 08; the characters are stored starting at 0x08
             ^
             |---------     &buffer is the memory location of buffer, and is 0x04
30 31 32 32 AB AB AB AB
^
|-------- char array starts at 0x08, and contains the string "1234"
```